# How do you ensure that these columns do not appear, since the value that appears already has something similar, such as ID and Date:

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I just added a code that inserts it into the table, but I don't believe it will add all these columns

[image]

```
package dborm

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type BotData struct {
    Name    string
    Message string
}

var dbBotData BotData

func SendDB() {
    dsn := "host=----- user=postgres password=------ dbname=---- port=----- sslmode=disable"
    var err error

    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("Falha ao conectar ao banco de dados")
    }

    err = db.AutoMigrate(&BotData{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("Falha ao aplicar migrações")
    }
    
    db.Delete(&dbBotData, 1)
    db.Create(&BotData{Name: "Samuel", Message: "121233"})

}
```

I tried using other methods but I was unsuccessful

Comment: Please indicate either you need GORM to add thse three columns and also fill them automatically as well as use soft-deltetion feature based on `deleted_at` column

Comment: Thank you, I managed to resolve it!! Share an answer so others with the same problem can see it more easily